# A program that can play video clips and recieve data while the clips are being played

Tags: java, video, interrupt

So I need to make a program (For now the program is in Java) that recives data ona countinuous basis and selects and displays video clips based on the data recived. I primarily need help on displaying video clips. {I have never made a program involving video clips) The program does not need to play the clips it self, For example the program can use Windows media player and the program selects and plays the clips (I have no idea on how to do that either and need help on it).
Example:
Suppose that there are 12 video clips, Named clip 1- clip 12.
The program starts by displaying a ramdom clip, suppose its clip2, now clip2 lasts 30 seconds so while clip2 is playing, data is being recieved.
Before "clip2" ends the data recieved is analyized and an array is generated representing which video clip is most preferred to be played. Suppose the array is [9,10,3,11,12,4,5,6,7,8,2,1], this would mean clip9 is the best choice and clip10 is the second best choice and so on. 
Therefore clip9 will be played next.
While Clip9 is being displayed data is still being recived continously and before Clip9 (a 35 second long clip) ends, the array [9,11,4,3,5,7,2...] is generated, now since clip9 was played recently it will not be played again and clip11 is played insted.
Now before Clip11 ends the array [2,9,10,5...] is generated, since clip2 was also played recently it will not be played but clip9 was played recently as well so clip10 will be played
Before Clip10 ends the array[2,10, 5...] is generated Clip2 has been played but it has not been played *recently* so in this case clip2 will be selected and displayed.
The program will need to be able to run indefinely long.

Note the Array does not need to be compiled just before a previous Clip ends it can be compiled just after the previous clip starts as long as clips are played continously with no interruptions.

Also the program will need to be able to recieve data continously

Comment: Wow!  That was a whole heapin' helpin' of words for no question.  Did you have a question, or were you just sharing that with us?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with Flex (or AIR if you want a desktop or android/iOS app) - in a weekend.  Take a peek at this tutorial, it does the basics of what you want from scratch in 7 minutes.

http://www.webkitchen.be/2009/01/06/video-tutorial-add-video-to-your-flex-application/

If you need the video streamed, take a look at Red5.  (http://www.red5.org/)

BTW, Flex/AIR is ActionScript which is ECMAScript - If you know java, you'll be completely comfortable with the syntax.